# Control Drop Down List from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a number of drop down lists and buttons that are created dynamically.
I need to write a piece of code that updates (in this case sets *enabled* to *false*) a drop down list after a user hits a certain button. Because everything is created dynamically I have to use Request.Form.AllKeys to find the ID of the drop down list. Which I am sussessfully able to do. However after I have found the ID I am unable to update the ddl in any way. How can I accomplish this?

```
    For Each ddlID In Request.Form.AllKeys
      If ddlID Like "ddl_*_" & number Then

      '' Need to figure out how to control the ddl from this point
      ddlID.


      End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage the [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) Method and Cast the result as a DropDownList:

```
Dim yourDropDownInstance as DropDownList = CType(Page.FindControl("ddl_" & number), DropDownList))
```

Note 1: You pass in the ID into the FindControl Method.

Note 2: Use FindControl off of whatever control you added your DropDownLists to.